# How often must Instituitions report their holdings to the SEC?

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-exchanges, sec

If one goes to the following page => https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PBF/holders?p=PBF

It shows the holding of various institutions for a particular stock. 2 questions here:

- How often do they have to report their holdings?
- Do they also have to report a ledger of transactions to the SEC?

Comment: Please define institution. Is it a pension fund, mutual fund, or something else?

Comment: Like Blackrock, Vanguard Group, as shown in the link